# T-SQL: create degree hierarchy and get highest degree rank

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

--I need to create a degree hierarchy on the fly where there's not a hierarchy in the database.
--The results needs to have the columns ID_NUM, DivisionDescMasters, SortOrder

--The hierarchy in order is listed next. I created the sort order with a case statement so now I need to pick the highest rank for each ID_NUM.
--The query cteminresults below shows the correct rows but I need to include the columns ID_NUM, DivisionDescMasters, SortOrder. How would I do that?

```
--    Hierarchy
--    DC Doctor
--    UG Undergrad
--    Graduate
--    Certificate
```

If I join the ctedivisiondesc and cteminresults as in cteminresults3 I get the right rows but it seems like a lot of queries to accomplish this result. Is this the most efficient method?

```
    WITH ctedivisiondesc AS
    (
    
        SELECT  ID_NUM,
                DIV_CDE,
                DEGR_CDE,
                DivisionDescMasters,
                SortOrder
        FROM    (   
        SELECT  DH1.ID_NUM,
                DH1.DIV_CDE,
                DH1.DEGR_CDE,
                CASE 
                    WHEN DIV_CDE = 'GR' THEN 'MASTERS'
                ELSE DDF.DEGREE_DESC
                END AS DivisionDescMasters,
                CASE 
                    WHEN DH1.DIV_CDE = 'CT' THEN 4
                    WHEN DH1.DIV_CDE = 'UG' THEN 2
                    WHEN DH1.DIV_CDE = 'GR' THEN 3
                    WHEN DH1.DIV_CDE = 'DC' THEN 1
                    --ELSE 0
                    END AS SortOrder
                FROM    Biz.dbo.DEGREE_HISTORY AS DH1
                        INNER JOIN Biz.dbo.DEGREE_DEFINITION AS DDF
                            ON DH1.DEGR_CDE = DDF.DEGREE
                WHERE ID_NUM = 174 OR ID_NUM = 1610 OR ID_NUM = 1103887 OR ID_NUM = 1105852
                    --Results of this statement
                    --ID_NUM    DIV_CDE DEGR_CDE    DivisionDescMasters SortOrder
                    --174       DC      DC          DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC      1* Select this one
                    --174       GR      MS          MASTERS                     3
                    --1610      DC      DC          DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC      1* Select this one
                    --1610      UG      BS          BACHELOR OF SCIENCE         2
                    --1610      UG      NDEG        Non-Degree Seeking          2
                    --1103887   UG      AAS         ASSOC OF APPLIED SCIENCES   2* Select any one of these
                    --1103887   UG      AAS         ASSOC OF APPLIED SCIENCES   2* Select any one of these
                    --1103887   UG      AAS         ASSOC OF APPLIED SCIENCES   2* Select any one of these
                    --1105852   UG      BS          BACHELOR OF SCIENCE         2
                    --1105852   DC      DC          DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC      1* Select this one
                    --1105852   UG      BS          BACHELOR OF SCIENCE         2
                    --1105852   UG      BS          BACHELOR OF SCIENCE         2
    
                ) AS t
        --WHERE   t.[SortOrder] = 1 --need max of sort order
        WHERE
        --AND 
        ID_NUM = 174 OR ID_NUM = 1610 OR ID_NUM = 1103887 OR ID_NUM = 1105852
        GROUP BY ID_NUM,
        DIV_CDE,
        DEGR_CDE,
        DivisionDescMasters,
        SortOrder
    )
    
    --SELECT * FROM ctedivisiondesc
    
    --ID_NUM    DIV_CDE DEGR_CDE    DivisionDescMasters     SortOrder
    --174       DC      DC          DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC      1
    --174       GR      MS          MASTERS                     3
    --1610      DC      DC          DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC      1
    --1610      UG      BS          BACHELOR OF SCIENCE         2
    --610       UG      NDEG        Non-Degree Seeking          2
    --1103887   UG      AAS         ASSOC OF APPLIED SCIENCES   2
    --1105852   DC      DC          DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC      1
    --1105852   UG      BS          BACHELOR OF SCIENCE         2
    
    ,cteminresults AS
    (
    
    SELECT  --'' cteminresults,
            ID_NUM,
            --DivisionDescMasters,
            MIN(SortOrder) SortOrder
    FROM    ctedivisiondesc
    WHERE ID_NUM = 174 OR ID_NUM = 1610 OR ID_NUM = 1103887 OR ID_NUM = 1105852
    GROUP BY ID_NUM
             --,DivisionDescMasters
    )
    
    --select * from cteminresults
    
    --ID_NUM    SortOrder
    --174           1
    --1610          1
    --1103887       2
    --105852        1
    --The correct SortOrder row was selected
    
    ,cteminresults2 AS
    (
    
    SELECT  --'' cteminresults,
            ID_NUM,
            DivisionDescMasters,
            MIN(SortOrder) SortOrder
    FROM    ctedivisiondesc
    WHERE ID_NUM = 174 OR ID_NUM = 1610 OR ID_NUM = 1103887 OR ID_NUM = 1105852
    GROUP BY ID_NUM
             ,DivisionDescMasters
    )
    
    --select * from cteminresults2 ORDER BY ID_NUM, SortOrder
    
    --ID_NUM    DivisionDescMasters     SortOrder
    --174       DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC          1
    --174       MASTERS                         3
    --1610      DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC          1
    --1610      BACHELOR OF SCIENCE             2
    --1610      Non-Degree Seeking              2
    --1103887   ASSOC OF APPLIED SCIENCES       2
    --1105852   DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC          1
    --1105852   BACHELOR OF SCIENCE             2
    --To many rows are selected


,cteminresults3 AS
(

SELECT  --'' cteminresults,
        cdd.ID_NUM,
        DivisionDescMasters,
        MIN(cdd.SortOrder) SortOrder
FROM    ctedivisiondesc cdd
INNER JOIN cteminresults cmm ON cdd.ID_NUM = cmm.ID_NUM
AND cdd.SortOrder = cmm.SortOrder
WHERE cdd.ID_NUM = 74 OR cdd.ID_NUM = 610 OR cdd.ID_NUM = 103887 OR cdd.ID_NUM = 105852
GROUP BY cdd.ID_NUM
         ,DivisionDescMasters
)

select * from cteminresults3 ORDER BY ID_NUM, SortOrder

--ID_NUM    DivisionDescMasters     SortOrder
--174       DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC          1
--1610      DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC          1
--1103887   ASSOC OF APPLIED SCIENCES       2
--1105852   DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC          1
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to test w/o test data (a picture of the data makes it really hard to validate), but here's what I'd do. I'd move your existing `[row number]` column out of the inner select into the CTE definition and change its definition to

```sql
row_number() over (
   partition by ID_Num
   order by SortOrder desc
) as [row number]
```

From there, you can do `select * from ctedivisiondesc where [row number] = 1;`.

That said, you have duplicate values in that column for a given ID_num, so which row the query produces will be arbitrary.